# Using Css transparent arrow over a line

Tags: jquery, css, menu, css-shapes

I need to convert a design to a html. Design shows an arrow transparent pointing to the currently selected tab.

Has I find it difficult I am using a filled triangle. I want to replace it with a thin transparent triangle.
Jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/np6ztcav/1/)

[triangle arrow like here](https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-07-128.png)

```
li {
      width:100px;
      list-style-type:none;
      float:left;  
      color:#fff;
       padding:10px 5px;
     position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
li.selected:after {
 border: 8px solid transparent;
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom-color:#fff;
 position:absolute; 
    bottom:-10px;
 left:40%;   
    content:' ';
}
```

I have used  thin image instead of css triangle my questions is how to make seamless line with a spike on it pointing the selected menu

--**^**--

Answer (score 1):

If your `<li>` is a same width, you can:

- remove border from `<ul>`
- apply border on all `<li>` not active
- On the active `<li>` you can user `:before` and `:after` simulate border
  arround the arrow.
- And you need to add element like span in your `<li>` for the arrow.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/np6ztcav/4/

Comment: I know how to place a image my question was how it overlays hover the line --^-- it should come as the continuous line with a spike to point where the menu selected

Comment: I will post it I found the solution from a website.